# Python - OpenCV clean blurred image

Tags: python, opencv, blurry

Is there a way I could clean a blurred image. I am using `python 2.7.7`. Suppose I have this image (Blurred):

[image: Blurred image]

Is there a way I clean this image to make it look like this?:

[image: Cleaned image]

Comment: Generally, no. A blur is a low pass filter, and it discards all the high frequency information from the image (that is, the details). You can compare the frequency domain representation of both images and you'll see the missing information.

Comment: The magical "zoom" or "enhance" from movies doesn't exist. At best you can guess at what the missing information was, and how good your guess will be depends on how good your model is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. And yes. If you know about blur function then you can partialy restore image. The simplest example - Wiener filter.

And OpenCV has some more complicated deblur functions, for your case - out of focus image: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/de/d3c/tutorial_out_of_focus_deblur_filter.html

Try it but do not expect magic results.